# TLPDB error during Vanilla Install of TeXLive 2020

Tags: software-installation, alpine-linux, latex

I'm trying to install TeXLive 2020 onto iSh (which uses Alpine Linux) and have extracted all files in the `install-tl-unx.tar.gz` tarball from the [TUG webpage](https://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html). However, when I execute `./install-tl` from the extracted directory I get the following error:

```
Loading http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb

./install-tl: TLPDB::from_file could not initialize from:
              http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb
./install-tl: Maybe the repository setting should be changed.
./install-tl: More info: https://tug.org/texlive/acquire.html
```

This happens whether or not I select a specific repository via the `--select-repository` option and happens both as root and normal user. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same error, so on a whim, I ran `sudo ./install-tl` and just saved the installation profile. I then chowned the texlive.profile file to my regular user. Running `./intall-tl` subsequently worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

`install-tl --help` mentions a `-v` option to enable verbose debugging.  In my case it showed

> D:TLUtils::download_file: tried to download using lwp curl wget, none succeeded

Trying `wget` on the target URL I found it was not able to check the certificate, which lead me to a broader certificate issue on my fresh Slackware install, which I was able to fix with

```
/usr/sbin/update-ca-certificates --fresh
```

Afterwards `install-tl` worked as expected.